# Will Turkish Airlines help me if I miss my connection?

Tags: transit, turkish-airlines, missed-flights, connecting-flights

If a miss my connecting flight when I transit at Istanbul Atatürk International Airport, will Turkish Airlines put me on another flight for free?

Comment: Are the flights on a single ticket, or were they booked separately?

Comment: Also, in which manner are you suggesting the flight is missed - a delayed incoming flight would be viewed entirely different to a passenger who simply wants another drink in the airport lounge...